# Angular Ionic 3 how to know if an image is loaded and if there are any errors on fetching the image url path

Tags: android, angular, image, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an **Ionic 3 App** where I am loading some **image** from an **API server**. In the **client-side** I want to know if the image is fetched or loaded successfully and I also want to know if there are any errors on fetching.

Here is the sample that I created using pure **html with angular template without any js**.

```
<img hidden [src]="driverInfo?.user_avatar?.url | image:'original'" (load)="this.loadingImage = false">
<img [src]="driverInfo?.user_avatar?.url | image:'original'" *ngIf="!loadingImage" onError="this.src='assets/imgs/avatar-placeholder.png';" />
```

When I only use the second line of code below and transfer the (load) event there. The `onError` path shows first which is not because the image is still loading. I want to show a spinner or loader when the image is loading. Then when the image has loaded show the **original path** if it **succeed** if not show the **path** in the **onError**.

So I know this code is not good at all. That's why I am trying to solve here. I just created a workaround code that achieves my goal but not in a good practice.

So in the first line of the code. I displayed a hidden **html file**. The purpose of this code is only to trigger if the image is loaded and in the second line is where the actual image is displayed if it is fetched successfully or show some error or image placeholder if not.

So how can I refactor this using **Angular JS**? Will I use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) with [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) to achieve this?

Appreciate if someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best would be to use `directive` since you may need this functionality in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve something like what you want using the following construction:

```
<img #thisImage src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" failedUrl="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" (error)="missingImage(thisImage.attributes.failedUrl.value)" onerror="this.src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'"/>
```

Here is stackblitz to play around: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-szz3nc

In short:

1. you want to assign additional attribute that will duplicate original value of 'src', I used 'failedUrl' as such. This is because on error src will get replaced with your placeholder safe url.
2. Now onerror - you want to replace failed url with placeholder
3. using (error) binding you can call a method and pass whatever you need to a ts function to act further (like I used to "report" such missing images).

Let me know if this is helpful.

Please note this type of code is super risky as if you make a mistake this can cause error loop (like if your safe placeholder url is also pointing nowhere).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers before, "onerror" property should work, except fot .svg images, so make sure that you are not using svg for the default image.

svg images on "onerror" property will work on browser, but not building with cordova.